# Can someone help me understand vectorization?

Tags: parallel-processing, vectorization

I'm really trying to wrap my head around vectorization but I can't seem to understand it. I don't know if I don't understand how to vectorize, or if I don't understand the array notation that's being used. An example of a loop I'm working on with school is below:

```
for (M=0; M< number_of_iterations/2; M++){
   for (i=2; i<n-1; i++)  
      for (j=1; j<n-1; j++)  
          y[i][j]= (x[i-1][j]+x[i][j-1]+x[i+1][j]+x[i][j+1]+x[i-2][j])/5.;
```

I'm not sure I quite understand the whole thing on dependencies - Is there a way to vectorize this using array notation as is, or do I need to adjust it somehow to account for dependencies throughout?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `x` and `y` are distinct arrays that don't overlap at all, there are no dependencies. `x` never changes, and all computations have results that only depend on `x`. No computation depends on the results of a prior computation.

The calculations and assignments used in that loop could occur in any order and with any concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

First I recommendo you to use brakets {} to organize your lines of code and understand it better.
Second, take a look to this page: http://www.javatutorialhub.com/java-arrays.html
Thirg, always start with easy examples to not get confused.